# How to validate parameter with array data type in Swagger 3.0.0

Tags: spring-boot, openapi, swagger-3.0

I have a swagger .yaml file which generates java class as below:

```
AlleleExportRequest:
      type: object
      properties:
         speciesId:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 17
          required: true
          minimum: 1
        assemblyId:
          type: integer
          format: int64
          example: 65
          required: true
          minimum: 1
        varIds:
          type: array
          example: [ 1,2 ]
          items:
            type: integer
            format: int64
```

Above swagger config generates **AlleleExportPost.java** class as follows:

```
@Validated
@javax.annotation.Generated
public class AlleleExportRequest {

  @JsonProperty("speciesId")
  private Long speciesId = null;

  @JsonProperty("assemblyId")
  private Long assemblyId = null;

  @JsonProperty("varIds")
  @Valid
  private List<Long> varIds = null;
}
```

When I send request to my controller from swagger UI, it is returning **400 error without any specific error message**. **varIds** should contain only integers as shown in config file, but If I send list of varIds which contains some String values, it is giving 400 error. How can I validate **varIds** and return proper error message in case it contains string values? Can I remove **@Valid** annotation from auto-generated java class or add some custom validation? Any help is appreciated. I tried **@Valid** annotation from controller but did not help.

MyController.java

```
@Override
public ResponseEntity<JobStatus> alleleMatrixExportPost(@Valid @RequestBody AlleleExportRequest body) {
    alleleMatrixService.setDefaultAggregationFilters(body);
        validateAlleleExportRequest(body);
        JobStatus response = alleleMatrixService.triggerAlleleExport(body);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

Example request with wrong varIds **'S1234'**

```
{
  "speciesId": 20,
  "assemblyId": 113,
  "varIds": ["12696767", "12696776","S1234"]
}
```